# Uploaded files not saving

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, files

I'm using EE 2.4, I have a file upload field in a matrix, when I upload a file and save the entry, it works fine, but when I reopen the entry to add new files, all the previously upload files are gone.

They're still on the server, I can see them in file manager, but they're not not in the entry anymore?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Matrix? Also: you really need to upgrade from EE 2.4.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your help.  Upgrading EE isn't really an option at this point unfortunately, but I've upgraded Matix to 2.4 (the latest one, 2.6 caused some database errors) and it seems to have fixed the issues.